# Getting values from mysql database to show in JSP (JAVA)

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I could use some help how to get values from a mysql database, and parse it to a servlet, which opens a jsp file "Showlist.jsp" and have all the values as parameter.

My tabel in my database contains:

```
ID, Name, Initials, cpr, password, role.
```

I have created 3 users in my system, and i want to show all users in a jsp file.

Right now i have 3 layers which contain the following classes:

**View layer**
- html / jsp files

**Function layer**
- Class function

**Data layer**
- Class DAOoperator (Contains mysql statements.
- Class DTOoperator (Which is my object with getter and setter methods)
- class DataAccess (contains connection to mysql database)

All this is controlled by a servlet called Controller.

Is there an easy way to do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the servlet you access the DAO and call the getUser() method which returns a list of user. Then you set the result to the request.

```
request.setAttribute("users", userList);
```

In the jsp you can get it by:

```
    <% List<User> userList = (List<User>)request.getAttribute("users"); %>
```

a better approach is to use jstl in the jsp instead of plain java code.

Comment: But, in the getUser() method in my DAO class, i should run a SElect * from tabel right?? and then what`?

Comment: **Never** suggest *Scriplet* in 21st century.

Answer (score 1):

**Never** use *Scriplet* in 21st century instead use [JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135995.html)

For more about [Oracle Tutorial - Using JSTL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL3.html)

---

**Logic:** Simply fetch the data form the database in Servlet and populate the data in a POJO class and set the final list of all the users as request attribute and finally forward the request to the JSP page.

Sample code:

User.java

```
public class User{
   private String ID, Name, Initials, cpr, password, role;
   // getter and setter       
}
```

Servlet:

```
List<User> list = new ArrayList<User>();
//fetch the record form database
// populate the record in User POJO class
// add the users in the list

// finally set the list as request attribute
request.setAttribute("users",list);

// forward the request to the JSP
request.getRequestDispatcher("/xyz.jsp").forward(request,response);
```

xyz.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<table border="1">
    <c:forEach items="${ requestScope.users}" var="user">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${user.ID }" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${user.Initials }" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${user.cpr }" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${user.role }" /></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```